# How to check whether a value already exists using AJAX in jQuery validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.validator.addMethod("noanon", function(value) {
return ajaxFunction();
}, 'Username already exists.');
```

The addMethod function takes 3 arguments. A name, the logic to actually run, and lastly, the default message to use for failures.

```
name: {
 required: true,
 minlength: 2,
 noanon: true
},
```

Now if I use the ajaxFunction, there sems to be some error which is appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `remote` method:

```
rules: {
    name: {
        remote : "script.php"
    }
},
messages: {
    name: {
        remote : "Page with this name is exists"
    }
}
```

In PHP you take `$_GET['name']`.

Additional information [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote)